# How to delete "app on facebook" platform correctly?

Tags: facebook

I have delete an "app on Facebook" platform and saved changes (in app settings). I also have ios, android, web site platforms. Now, when i type name of my app in Facebook search bar it is in search results, and when i click on it, Facebook redirects me on a page with error message that i have wrong settings of canvas page. at where i am doing wrong?

(app was removed 30 minutes ago)

[App settings screenshot](http://cubeupload.com/im/BHto5C.png)

"Error
Sorry, the application you were using is misconfigured. Please try again later.
Message for Developers Only:
To fix this error, please set your Canvas URL and/or Secure Canvas URL in the "App on Facebook" section of your app's settings. Once it has been set, your users will be redirected to that URL instead of this error page."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sounds of it you've added a canvas (now known as FB App I believe) app but haven't put the canvas URLs in so it doesn't know what URL to fetch within the canvas frame.

This may provide some more info https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/

[image: Make sure you enter a canvas and secure canvas URL]

Comment: Yes I added a FB app, but then a deleted it. Now I have ios, android and website platforms only. But search bar still redirects on canvas page. (sorry for my English)

Comment: It can take a while for it to be removed from search results due to server propagation. Please edit your post with a screenshot of the app settings (showing platforms, remove sensitive info) and tell us how long ago you removed the app